# Unable to connect to the database mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I've downloaded the wamp server and it's online. I'm trying to install Joomla.

[image: description]

At page 4 I'm told `Unable to connect to the database`

[image: description]

> An error has occurred:The database details provided are incorrect and/or empty.

Can anyone help me in fixing this error?

This problem has been fixed by Ocaso Protal, finaly this page ocurs
[image: description]

what should I put here ?Site Name? nd finaly why should i use joomla any specific properties of this product ?

Comment: @stan have you already created the database?

Comment: Did you type in a username (and possibly password)? In the screenshot you've typed neither.

Comment: from the first screen it seems you've forhotten about username and password

Comment: Can you connect to the database with another client?

Comment: @icktoofay:) in localhost password is root by default .... and password is null

Comment: @JohnP:) ya i created database with name harsh ...

Comment: @k102:) in localhost username is root and password is null by default so no need to add username and password

Comment: @Stan, null password? as i remember mysql win installer won't allow you to leave null password

Comment: @Stan Empty password should be correct, but please put the username `root` in the appropriate field

Comment: @Stan try to remember your password =) and you really shouldn't leave `user name` field blank

Comment: @Ocaso you could make that an answer

Comment: @Ocaso Protal:) and also i want to know this ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137970/joomla-question-is-it-possible-to-use-different-databasepostgresql-instead-of

Comment: @Stan: Sorry, can't help you with the postgresql question. But MySQL is not that hard to learn and from my knowledge with CMS I would not recommend to exchange the underlying database, because that is often too cumbersome and gives you a lot of problems.

Comment: @Ocaso Protal:) question edited

Comment: @Pekka:) what should i do if i have confusion to select the best ans ?means if both question are true nd have the same votes from hary

Comment: @Stan just select the one that you think helped the most. No one will begrudge you your decision as the community votes in parallel to your decision.

Comment: @JohnP:) i wil folow u on twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check these things before

1. Setup a blank database from the Cpanel/Mysql Admin
2. Fix the username/password and user permissions on this database
3. Run Joomla... and give it the above credentials + localhost
4. Make sure you have 777 or adequate permissions otherwise some errors may occur#

If im not mistaken the default account for wamp/xamp myqsl is 
user: "root"
password: ""

//Password is null - do not write nothing inside

Comment: Sitename is the title that will be used in a lot of positions (you can use Test Site)

Comment: and email and password are used to login into the backend part when you write /administrator/ (dont forget to delete the installation folder)

Depends what you want.. I recommend Joomla for a Static Kind of website where there is no blogs, carts and things like this but for those 10 pager websites. You can do a lot with it of course its just my opinion

Comment: @MRR:) can u add some more information about joomla in your ans plz,

Comment: If this is for testing you can make sample data just to have sample modules and pages to see what Joomla got..

Basically if you need something there is the Joomla Repository which has all kinds of modules.... so the limitations on Joomla is very low... If you want a shopping cart there is VirtueMart, If you want a blog there is a phpBB plugin etc etc

Comment: @MRR:) last question finaly i del instalation folder but it show msg-PLEASE REMEMBER TO COMPLETELY
REMOVE THE INSTALLATION DIRECTORY.
You will not be able to proceed beyond this point until the installation directory has been removed. This is a security feature of Joomla!.
Click here when the directory has been removed.

Comment: You removed it from the FTP/htdocs completely ? just right click delete on the folder of the installation.. then just go to localhost and check if it still pops an error (at this point you can get out of the installation)

Comment: @MRR:) ya got it actualy i uses two hosts .. thats why i m confused i deleted from localhost ... finaly it works.

Comment: FYI you should never use 777 permissions on a Joomla install, it is not required, it's a security issue, and a bad habit to get in, even on localhost. Folders should be 755 and files should be 644.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you use the default settings for mysql (user: `root`, password empty) you should put the username `root` in the Username field in the form that's showed in your first screenshot.