# Not able to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to connect to the database mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148588/unable-to-connect-to-the-database-mysql)

I was trying PHP web crawler for website http://astellar.com

I did everything step by step and also create user and database for MySQL. Then connect to database with user as well but it show me an error.

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'switsolu_kll'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/switsolu/public_html/crawler/_db.php on line 43
Cannot connect to database server (Reason: Access denied for user 'switsolu_kll'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
```

where I am wrong in there?

Comment: Can you tell in specific which part of the error message you do not trust and for which reason/assumption?

Comment: >>  see http://sw19itsolutions.com/search.php

Comment: Did you give your database user the required permissions?

Comment: yess all permission, full access

Comment: i use cpanel ,,  and create by there and give access...

Comment: should i give 777 permission?

Comment: @JackMihai: even 755 permission will also work

Comment: Recheck your password for connecting to MySQL

Comment: @rekenerd  i recheck that...  password is ok... 

the senario is , i put passowrd in _config.php... and i am accessing search.php
and it show me that  put wrong in _db.php

Answer (score 1):

This error almost always appears when the MySQL password is wrong. Check, double check and then triple check that it is correct.

Comment: Hi,  i check, then i recheck and then i triple check, it was all ok...

But i didnt put any password and anything in file _db.php
i put in _config.php

and it show me that now... i made a new user and passord verycarefully again and put again....

Comment: @JackMihai I suggest you show us exactly how you try to connect to MySQL. It probably isn't more than 5 - 10 lines of code.

Comment: its many files... i am putting few of line,, which manual say to edit...

_config.php

// *** MySQL database config. Please change these lines according your host
$s_op['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$s_op['mysql_db'] = "switsolu_aaa";
$s_op['mysql_user'] = "switsolu_aaa";
$s_op['mysql_pass'] = "abc123abc.";

Answer (score 1):

Often when you created user you did not declare the proper hostname or the request is coming from a host other than 'localhost'.  You can create the user for wildcard for all hosts, but sometimes the order of rules messes it up.

- delete user and recreate

  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON switsolu_aaa.* TO 'switsolu_kll'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'abc123abc';
- don't forget to flush privileges

  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

And depending on your app, you may need to restart it or the server to reset socket connection and retry but shouldn't have to, just retry.

If the localhost doesn't work, then delete user and recreate with 'switsolu_kll'@'%'  instead.  Don't forget flush privileges; after creating user.

Answer (score 0):

Check User Permission. If you running local, and  still have root try:

```
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$mysqlusername  = "root";
$mysqlpassword  = "";
?>
```