# Could not connect to MySQL with Joomla and 'Site offline' checked

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have my Joomla 2.5 application with Site Offline checked. I have stopped my MySQL server and I was expecting Joomla rendering the site offline page, however I get a 'Can't connect to MySQL' page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to ping : is the connection closed?

Comment: I am using localhost, and I stopped MySQL in purpose to see if the offline page was showing...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148588/unable-to-connect-to-the-database-mysql?rq=1

Comment: .... My question is: Why would the offline site not show up due to MySQL problems?

Comment: Joomla site offline still needs the database. All that does is put up a page that prevents people from seeing your site, it doesn't actually take your site offline.

Answer (score 0):

The index.php in the root of the site is first run when the site is visited this file goes through a series of checks one of them being able to access the Database, after the checks it examines the config file to see if the site-offline flag has been set.